# ¿Como separar el cuerpo del tabs?

Tags: css, vue.js

Estoy implementando este codigo o quiero implementarlo en mi sitio web.Es un tab en VueJs. En mi sitio web tengo una barra o nav fija en la parte de arriba.Los botones de este tabs los quiero poner en el nav fijo y el contenido en el cuerpo. Tengo un incoveniente con este codigo y es que el contenido está dentro de #App y cuando lo saco no funciona.Pienso que asi es que lo reconoce este framework.

Mi duda es: ¿Hay alguna forma de sacar esto del contenedor "id=app":

```
 <section class="mainBody">
<router-view name="header"></router-view>
<router-view name="content"></router-view>
</section>
```

**Script.js**

```js
const Home = {
  template: `
    <section class="content">This is the home screen.</section>
  ` };

const contentOne = {
  template: `<section class="content">Content One</section>` };

const contentTwo = {
  template: `<section class="content">






  </section>` };

const contentThree = {
  template: `<section class="content">



  </section>` };

const contentFour = {
  template: `<section class="content">Content Four</section>` };

const contentFive = {
  template: `<section class="content">Content Five</section>` };


const Header = {
  template: `
    <section class="header">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="left">
          <h1 :style="titleStyles" :class="classList">{{title}}</h1>
          <p v-if="text">{{text}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div v-if="action"><button @click="doAction">Call {{action}}</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="top">
        <div class="left">
          <p>{{description}}</p>
          
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <p v-show="showMessage">You called method {{action}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
    </section>
  `,
  computed: {
    titleStyles() {
      return `color: ${this.color}`;
    },
    classList() {
      return this.customClasses.join(' ');
    } },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      // reset showmessage
      vm.showMessage = false;
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showMessage: false };

  },
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'orange' },

    customClasses: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: [] },

    title: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'YOU MUST PUT A TITLE HERE!!!' },

    text: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'Default Text' // this default will not work if 'config' object is passed to route. Even if it is empty.
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'Default description' },

    action: {
      type: String,
      required: false } },


  methods: {
    doAction() {
      this.showMessage = !this.showMessage;
      this[this.action]();
    },
    actionOne() {
      console.log('Action one called.');
    },
    actionTwo() {
      console.log('Action two called.');
    } } };




const routes = [
{ path: '/', name: 'home', components: { content: Home } },
{ path: "/one", name: 'one', components: { header: Header,
    content: contentOne }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/two", name: 'two', components: { header: Header, content: contentTwo }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/three", name: 'three', components: { header: Header, content: contentThree }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/four", name: 'four', components: { header: Header, content: contentFour }, props: { header: true, content: false } },
{ path: "/five", name: 'five', components: { header: Header, content: contentFive }, props: { header: true, content: false } }];


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
});

const app = new Vue({
  router }).
$mount("#app");
```

```css
#app {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  padding: 2rem;
}

code {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.mainBody {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

nav.mainNav > * {
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav.mainNav > *:nth-last-child(n+2) {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.header {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.header h1.classOne {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.header .top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Vue Router and Reusable Components</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Router and Reusable Components</h1>

  <nav class="mainNav">
    <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}">Home</router-link>
    <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'one', params: { color: 'red', title: 'Page One', description: 'Color and Title set. Default Text.' } }">One</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'two', params: { color: 'green', customClasses: ['classOne'], title: 'Page Two', description: 'This is our new description.' } }">Two</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'three', params: { color: 'purple', text: 'This is some random text.', description: 'Color and Text set. Default Title.' } }">Three</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'four', params: { title: 'Page Four', action: 'actionOne', description: 'Only Title set. Action One.' } }">Four</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'five', params: { action: 'actionTwo', description: 'All Defaults. Action Two.' } }">Five</router-link>
  
  </nav>






  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <section class="mainBody">
    <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    <router-view name="content"></router-view>
  </section>




</div>




<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/2.5.3/vue-router.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Este es el modelo de lo que quiero.Una barra fija(Navbar) con los botones del tab.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sobre "¿Hay alguna forma de sacar esto del contenedor `"id=app"`?" > No, sobre el div con id app es donde se monta la instancia de Vue, fuera de ahí no podrás usar código de vue o vue-router como `<router-view name="header"></router-view>`. Por lo demás no entiendo qué es lo que quieres lograr. ¿Podrías explicar un poco más lo de "Los botones de este tabs los quiero poner en el nav fijo y el contenido en el cuerpo"?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Con solo decirme eso,la primera parte,ya entendí. Uffff.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ La proxima pregunta seria: ¿Cómo rayos pongo datos en un template Vue traidos desde una bd con PHP(plano)?Jejeje.

Comment: Para eso tendrías que crear otra pregunta, pero básicamente si el php te devuelve los datos en formato JSON, desde vue haces una llamada ajax a la url del php guardando el json de la respuesta en una variable (una propiedad 'items` en `data` por ejemplo), luego en el template [iteras](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) sobre esa variable pintando el resultado.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨMuchas gracias por tus respuestas.Ah!Una cosa mas respecto a  eso,¿tambien funciona con fotos o  imagenes?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Edité mi pregunta y añadí una imagen como referencia

Comment: No hay mucho que hacer con vue ahí, más que lo que ya tienes. El problema tiene que ver con el css. Prueba con una guía como [esta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_CSS_Grid_Layout) y si te encuentras con algún obstáculo actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas intentado.